# Is using Javascript to validate "Confirm password" input, adding any security risk?

Tags: javascript, html

I searched on SO and found that:
[Is javascripts access to a password fields value considered a security risk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631134/is-javascripts-access-to-a-password-fields-value-considered-a-security-risk)

However, it doesn't say if using Javascript to do something like compare "password" and "confirm password" adds a security threat to the one already existing?

Thanks a lot if you could clarify this matter. Regards

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Javascript validation, you just have to have validation on the server side as well, because Javascript validation doesn't give you any security benefits. It can make the user experience better though, by validating immediately instead of on a new page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would your script do once it confirms that the two passwords are the same?  If it sends the password over the wire, you are back to the exact question you linked to.

Even if you do not send the password anywhere the risk od code injection still remains

So, no additional security risk, but is does not remove any either

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. All I want to do with JS is compare both password, and if they don't match, I preventDefault() the button, until they match. So I guess I'm fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. If security threats were posed by comparing strings with JavaScript, nobody would do it. JavaScript is a client-side language; there's no network activity for anyone to sniff, if that's what you mean.